# SharePoint 2010 accessing a list via Data Services

Tags: sharepoint-2010, wcf-data-services

We have just finished deploying SharePoint 2010 in our company,
When i try to access a data service endpoint it simply times out (either through code or browser)
The endpoint i am trying to his is http://......./Site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ProductionLinks()
If i then browse the list and retry the link it will then work. it then also works for other people accessing the data service but it seems that someone needs to browse the list with IE first (and maybe spin up the site). then after aproximatly 30 min the Data Services requests will stop working.

Is there a way to make a data service call access a SharePoint List without having to browse it first with IE?
Or is there some SharePoint config item I need to set?

Comment: what does the iis service for that port look like when it is unresponsive? use `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list wp` to get the process id for that port